# Windowtester script button click doesn't respond

Tags: eclipse, window-tester

I am trying to test an eclipse plugin application using windowtester. 
After writing the test I was able to run it successfully. But, after a few runs and 
few manual interruptions while running, now it doesn't respond to the button click.

If I run the application as such, it responds.

Please let me know if I should clear something???